# Will a Yeast Starter Exposed to Sunlight Materially Effect the Beer?

Tags: yeast-starters, light

I know not to expose a fermenting carboy to sunlight, but is it OK to expose a yeast starter? I have two of them next to a window with blinds that are ineffective at blocking sunlight. I didn't think about it until now. May I proceed with brewing or should I throw these yeast starters down the drain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the starter was not hopped, you should be ok since the hops are needed to produce the skunky flavors.

The UV radiation in sunlight can [damage](http://www.angelfire.com/planet/crrussell220/Final_Manuscript.htm) yeast cells, but they are capable of self-repair to a degree, so there should still be plenty of viable cells to continue fermentation.

It's a good idea to not pitch the spent starter wort in general, here, I would definitely decant most of the liquid and pitch just the yeast to be on the safe side.